# ERROR InstantiatingNullHandler Could not create and/or set value back on to object

Tags: spring, spring-security, struts2

I have upgraded struts library to latest version 2.5.10.1.

When I am trying to set back a object from JSP I am getting following error.

```
    ERROR InstantiatingNullHandler Could not create and/or set value back on to object
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'userExtraInfoList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain' to required type 'com.***.user.UserExtraInfo' for property 'userExtraInfoList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:605)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:617)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1536)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:215)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:194)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.createObject(InstantiatingNullHandler.java:149)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.nullPropertyValue(InstantiatingNullHandler.java:125)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlNullHandlerWrapper.nullPropertyValue(OgnlNullHandlerWrapper.java:21)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:118)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.setValueBody(ASTChain.java:222)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
    at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:710)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$1.execute(OgnlUtil.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$1.execute(OgnlUtil.java:287)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:382)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:287)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:184)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:153)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:125)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:69)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:88)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:120)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain' to required type 'com.***.user.UserExtraInfo' for property 'userExtraInfoList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:574)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    ... 118 more
```

I suspect there is some library mismatch.

I am using following struts library

```
struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
struts2-convention-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
struts2-junit-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
struts2-spring-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
struts2-tiles-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
```

Spring Library

```
spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserInfo")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UserID")
    private String userID;

    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "Department")
    private String department;

    @Transient
    private String designation;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    @Transient
    private Role[] roleList;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<UserExtraInfo> userExtraInfoList;

    .
    .
    Other Getter and setters

    public List<UserExtraInfo> getUserExtraInfoList() {
        return userExtraInfoList;
    }

    public void setUserExtraInfoList(List<UserExtraInfo> userExtraInfoList) {
        this.userExtraInfoList = userExtraInfoList;
    }
}
```

Actually I am not setting any vlaues to userExtraInfoList from JSP.

If I remove the userExtraInfoList then it works, but it is being used in later part of code. Could you please help to resolve this issue.

In JSP I am doing following ajax call

```
function getReportingManagersList(){
    var department = $('#department').val();
    var designation = $('#designation').val();
    $.ajax({
        data:{'user.department':department,'user.designation':designation},
        url:'getReportingManagersList',
        datatype:'json',
        success:function(json, textStatus){
            .
            .
            .
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error while getting reporting manager list' + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Action class

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable, ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware, ServletContextAware {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserAction.class);

    private UserService userService;
    private User user;
    .
    .
    .


    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        super.prepare();
    }



    public void getReportingManagersList() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("get reporting manager list for department : "
                        + user.getDepartment() + " and designation : "
                        + user.getDesignation());
        try {
            List<User> userList = userService.getUserList(user);
            StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder("{");
            if (!userList.isEmpty()) {
                int index = 1;
                for (User user : userList) {
                    json.append("'");
                    json.append(user.getUserID());
                    json.append("':'");
                    json.append(user.getUserName());
                    json.append("'");
                    if (index < userList.size()) {
                        json.append(",");
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
            json.append("}");
            streamJsonToClient(json.toString().replaceAll("'", String.valueOf('"')));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error", e);
            throw (e);
        }
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Forbidden</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
            <http-method>CONNECT</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>     
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>      

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
        720
        </session-timeout>
        <cookie-config><http-only>true</http-only></cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>jsp/forward.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I am doing save user action, that action is not working because of this exception.

Comment: post the code what you doing.

Comment: Use Struts json plugin.

Comment: I already have **struts2-json-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar**.

Comment: Having is not the same as using.

Comment: It is in class path, and as I mentioned earlier, If I remove List<UserExtraInfo> userExtraInfoList; from User object, it works. Is there any problem in web.xml? I made sample project using same library only difference I made is I didn't include spring security features in web.xml then it started working. Along with struts library I upgraded spring security also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downgrading spring framework version to 4.2.9.RELEASE, issue is resolved.